# create admin for spree for the app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, spree-auth-devise

How can I create an admin for my app which is running on heroku with spree.

Here's what I am trying but doesn't seem to be working.

```
new_admin=Spree::User.create(:email=>"test@gmail.com",
:password =>"testtest", :password_confirmation =>"testtest")
```

I am going into `heroku rails console`, and trying it.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `heroku run` command.

Spree has it's own rake command to create an admin user.

from terminal run below command

`heroku run rake spree_auth:admin:create`

Comment: This answer worked for me (Spree 4.0) `heroku run bundle exec rake spree_auth:admin:create`